# Al instalar Moodle da error "La instalación debe finalizarse desde la misma dirección IP original"

Tags: moodle

Estoy intentando instalar manualmente Moodle en un Hostinger, pero por temas de conectividad tuve que cerrar mi maquina y al retomar la instalacion me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da una solución actualizando la IP, ya que al parecer re inicie mi equipo y tengo otra IP, sin embargo, revisando la solucion para este ISSUE confirmo que la IP que esta en la base de datos es la misma de mi maquina. Alquien me puede dar una luz de que mas puedo revisar o cambiar para avanzar con mis practicas. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Qué dice cuando tocas más información? Tal vez ayude a responderte. Copialo como texto por favor.

Comment: @mateo me envia a este link de documentación: https://docs.moodle.org/all/es/error/admin/installhijacked Basicamente, que actualice la ip en la base de datos y es lo que realice, sin embargo, tiene la misma IP del equipo donde estoy conectado a Hostinger e intentando instalar desde la web respectiva. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion es comentar la validacion en el archivo (linea 755) index.php que se encuenra en la carpeta de moodle en el directorio admin.

```
    if ($adminuser->password === 'adminsetuppending') {
    // prevent installation hijacking
    /*if ($adminuser->lastip !== getremoteaddr()) {
        print_error('installhijacked', 'admin');
    }*/
```

Guardar el archivo con el cambio y presionar el boton para retomar la instalacion.